# Rename iOS 10 Memories

Tags: photos.app, ios

There is a memory I would like to save on my phone, but the name of it is just the name of my home town, which is quite boring. I know by default it looks like all the memory names are just the name of where the photo was taken.

I was wondering **is there a way to change memory names?**

Answer (score 4):

Open the memory and tap on the existing title. The video will start playing. Tap again anywhere on the screen, then tap <sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub> and set the name as the title.